# How to debug any further?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, pyinstaller

I'm building an executable file with PyInstaller and the building completes successfully. Even running the created .exe-file works without any error message. But the script ends very early and not getting past some imports. I've tracked it down to the pandas import statement but now I have no clue how to debug what goes wrong because I'm not getting any error messages.

I've already tried to check the building log messages and using the debug flag with `imports` or `bootloader` but I can't find any useful messages which import statement or code inside pandas is causing the end of the script.

Installed versions:

- Python: 3.6.13
- PyInstaller: 4.2
- Pandas: 1.1.5

Getting the same behaviour with this code:

```py
# test.py
import pandas as pd

def main():
    print(pd.__version__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now building with `pyinstaller test.py` also completes successfully but when executing the test.exe inside my build folder no output is created and the script ends without any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by a bug. Use latest development version of PyInstaller to fix it.

I've opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5589).